# UIAlertView button text does not display

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm attempting to get a simple alert message to display in my app. I am using the code recommended by Apple, but every time the Cancel button displays without its text. I don't believe I have any other code that could override the default display of the alert.

Screenshot can be seen [here](http://imgur.com/KXRe5T9).

Here's my code to display the alert:

```
NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No results found for '%@'.", @"TEST"];
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search Error"
                                                   message:alertMessage
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

[theAlert show];
```

When I use `NSLog(@"%@", [theAlert buttonTitleAtIndex:0]);` to log the title, it outputs "Cancel" just fine.

Comment: Are you using some additional categories for `UIAlertView` or for `UIView`? Maybe you are using `UIApperance` and set `contentInset` for `UIView`? Not many details in the question.

Comment: I don't have any categories for `UIAlertView` or `UIView`, just one on `UIViewController` that sets up the navigation bar. I get the same issue when I completely remove the category. There are also no references to `UIApperance`.

Comment: At first please open simulator and select from menu "Reset Content and Settings", then Cmd+Shift+K on Xcode to clean the project. Run it again and check.

Comment: Still the same issue after resetting content and settings and cleaning the project.

Comment: That code is correct have you restarted xcode? Is this behaviour on both simulator and device?

Comment: Have you tried making a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The alert works fine in a minimal example, where all it does is run the code listed above. There is definitely something in my main project that is interfering, I just can't seem to find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment, but I have low reputation for it... Anyway, I had simmilar issue with UIButton, and I figured out, it was bug in Xcode 6. Have you tried Xcode 5?

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Xcode 6 yet - still on 5.1.1 - but thanks for the thought

Comment: Np, and if you'll try to create this exactly the same alert on viewDidLoad? Does it appear correctly?

Comment: I tried creating the same alert in the viewDidLoad of my very first view controller and it still appears without button text. I never figured to have so much trouble doing something so basic...

Comment: ok, tried it in my project, and it works without any troubles... Try to create NSString *cancel = @"Cancel" and put it in cancelButtonTitle